# How to add a context menu entry to the eclipse editor context menu

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, e4

I'm trying to create a plugin for eclipse and for the one of the requirements is to add an entry to the context menu for all text editors so that on right click I get an option corresponding to the action I want to perform. I've tried to find relevant resources for it but most of the use cases are focused on adding a context menu to a view etc and not to the context menu for the eclipse editor. So far, I tried to implement this using the eclipse context in the activator but as is perhaps obvious, the workspace is not created when the activator's start method executes. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You would normally use the `org.eclipse.ui.menus` extension point for that

Comment: I actually did that using org.eclipse.ui.menus extension point as you mentioned but I thought that there would be different way to do it in e4 applications or in my case in the e4fragment.xmi. Have I misunderstood because I thought that this paradigm was only limited to Eclipse 3 applications?

Comment: Also, just piggybacking off of this question, is there any documentation on menu item ids, since I would like to place my context menu contribution at a specific place and I was using the after keyword but I wasn't able to find out the relevant ids for placing them.

Comment: You can probably do it in the fragment.xmi using a MenuContribution, but I haven't tried this for contributing to existing 3.x compatability mode plug-ins

Comment: [Eclipse plug-in spy](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePlatformDevelopment/article.html#eclipse_ide_spies) can show some information about menus (see section 8.3 in the link) but for the menu id I think you need to look at the source or other menu contributions

Comment: I tried that approach but unfortunately the after and before keywords don't work with the relevant ids. Also, fyi the menu contribution approach works, we just need to set the parent id as #TextEditorContext (or whatever the use case maybe) however, this still requires the handler to implement the IHandler interface. One last question regarding this, using IHandler means that e4 dependency injection doesn't work (the execute method overrides the default method which doesn't allow extra arguments); is there a possible alternative to this?